# Kuberentes - run pods from "Deployment X" only on nodes where pods from "Deployment Y" do not exist

Tags: kubernetes

I want to deploy some pods (from deployment X) only on nodes where pods from deployment Y do not exist.
Is there a way to make something like that?
First idea is to use node affinity and deploy X on nodes with label X and Y where there is no X, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about "Inter-pod" affinity and anti-affinity.
What I mean is "I would like to avoid adding labels to nodes" and use node selector.

This could what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inter pod affinity and Anti affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity). Here is the relevant snippet from the documentation:

> Inter-pod affinity and anti-affinity allow you to constrain which
> nodes your Pods can be scheduled on based on the labels of Pods
> already running on that node, instead of the node labels.
>
> Inter-pod affinity and anti-affinity rules take the form "this Pod
> should (or, in the case of anti-affinity, should not) run in an X if
> that X is already running one or more Pods that meet rule Y", where X
> is a topology domain like node, rack, cloud provider zone or region,
> or similar and Y is the rule Kubernetes tries to satisfy.